# Single-column primary key in one table, but two or more similar columns in another table eg Drug Interacton database

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to create a data base schema for drug Interaction.

A Drug Interaction is a phenomenon where, when two or more drugs are given to a patient around the same time, the combined effects are not what might be expected if the two were not given individually- sometimes, the drugs cancel each other out, sometimes, one drug increases the toxic effects of the other etc.

My database schema now look like

drug(drugid pk, generic name )

Interaction(drugid1 fk,drugid2 fk, outcome, interactionID integer identity)

This works only for 2 drug interaction it does not work for 2 or more interaction.
How do i solve this problem?

I tried like the answer mentioned below but I m stuck at this point

my table looks like

InteractionId  outcome

1              death

2             heart attack

drugid        interactionid

1               1

2               1

3               1

2               2

5               2

now if I query

> select interactionid from participating_drug where drugid =1 or drugid
>   =2 or drugid =3

I will get both interaction id 1 and 2 but I should get only 1

Answer (score 1):

Define the following tables:

```
drug --like yours
interaction (interactionID int identity, outcome)
participating_drug (drugid, interactionid)
```

In any interaction there are multiple drugs involved.

Comment: I tried this but I cannt query with the interactionid .for example I have 3 drugs .My query will look like select transactionid from participating_drug where drugid = "a" or drugid="b" or drugid="c" .which will pull all transactionid's involving these drug not one row ..i m confused only in this part .

Comment: Why would you expect just one row in this case? I mean, one drug can be in interaction with multiple drugs, right?

Comment: I should know only what will be the outcome if I prescribe drug a+ drug b+ drug c together .if I use this I will get results or outcomes of drug a and some other combinations also

Comment: I made few updates in the question regarding where I m stuck .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it in this way

```
DRUG
drugid     100................200
drugname   aspirin............kryptonite sulfate
etc


OUTCOME
outcomeid 12345
outcome_description  e.g. loss of muscle tone when kryptonite sulfate and aspirin are mixed

OUTCOME_DRUG
outcomeid (references OUTCOME.outcomeid)
drugid  (references DRUG.drugid
```

OUTCOME_DRUG is in a many-to-one relationship with OUTCOME.   OUTCOME is the "anchor".

For the query:
[Select users who own both a dog and a cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463692/select-users-who-own-both-a-dog-and-a-cat)

(select outcomes involving both kryptonite sulfate and aspirin)